# how to retrieve data from firestore based on date range?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Need to fetch all data rows from my collection("data") with my ID and date range as below

```
  Date start = new Date(01/4/2022);
  Date end = new Date(30/4/2022);

fStore.collection("data").whereEqualTo("ID", userId).where("date", ">=",start ).where("date", "<=", end).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
```

But its complaining using 2 where clauses
[image]

Answer (score 0):

solution which helped me is using .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("date", "01/5/2022").whereLessThanOrEqualTo("date", "31/5/2022").